# What does Mr.Freeze shoot from his freeze gun?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe, batman-the-animated-series, mr-freeze

In the *Batman: The Animated Series* episode ["Heart of Ice"](https://batman.fandom.com/wiki/Heart_of_Ice), Mr. Freeze shoots what seems to be ice from his freeze gun, but is it ice or something else?

When Mr. Freeze "freezes" the legs of one of his henchmen, they are forced to leave him, but Batman rescues him using a chemical bath. If it was just ice, why couldn't Batman just wait for it to melt?

Mr. Freeze traps Batman with the "ice" but he punches and kicks his way out.  I understand why he didn't want to wait because Mr. Freeze and his henchmen are driving away.

Comment: It takes a while to melt a large chunk of ice; maybe Batman didn't want to wait that long to grab the henchman?

Comment: @DavidW - It's possible, but in a scene in the Batcave, he places the henchmen in a chemical bath that melts the "ice", he could have just waited for it to melt at room temperature. Given Mr. Freeze is a smart scientist, he probably engineered a new type of ice, a type that's difficult to melt under normal circumstances.

Comment: In the DC comic continuity, his gun shoots *"Waves of frigid cold"*

Comment: If one were simply wait for ice to melt to free someone trapped in it, one may well find the person inside suffering from frostbite, hypothermia, shock - potentially crippling or fatal levels of injury. Icy cold is dangerous, and ice is slow to melt. Even ice cubes can *hurt* before melting, ice thick enough to trap a person is definitely gonna do some damage.  It could be the chemical melting bath was needed to save life or limb, and letting that damage happen when an alternative was available, would not suit superhero ethics.  There may be other reasons, but this seems a possible one.

Comment: @Megha - I think that's the closest answer I'm going to get, make it a real answer and I'll give you the check mark.